# Check if facebook user likes some specific pages given page id

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Let's say I'm monitoring user likes of pages 10000, 10001 and 10002.

As far as I can see, I can do this by...

- Reading `/$user_id/likes` and search for my ids in there
- Issue a request for each id and check whether it is empty or not, eg: `/$user_id/likes/$page_id`

Both solutions take up more than one request for something that should be easily available in just one. Something like: `/$user_id/likes/?ids=10000,10001,10002`

But I can't seem to find anything that suggests this is possible. Ideas?